# JMS over secure channel?

Tags: security, jms

I have worked on web application where we could use https for secure channel. I am not sure
is there any thing similar so that jms messages are transported securely? By default active mq
uses tcp protocol . Probably to make the transportation secure can we https or some other alternative
is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up SSL for JMS, if that is what you are asking, is easy. Just configure certificates for your broker and client and then point them to the respecive trust/keystores.

1. Using keytool, create a certificate for the broker.
2. Export the broker's certificate so it can be shared with clients.
3. Create a certificate/keystore for the client.
4. Create a truststore for the client, and import the broker's certificate. This establishes that the client "trusts" the broker.

https://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-ssl.html